# How to use multiple counts to make a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a hard question to ask. However, I have this code so far:

```
#create the dictionary with the word profiles

        for u in unique:
            kw = u
            count_word = [i for i in temp for j in i.split() if j == kw]
            count_dict = {j: i.count(j) for i in count_word for j in i.split() if j != kw}
            print(kw)

            #format the dictionary
            for a, c in sorted(count_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):
                print('{}: {}'.format(a, c))
            print()
```

This does exactly what I want it to do except, the unique words need a counter as well. In the example below, I have river as the unique word and it will go through the code and compare against the temp list. It's output is as follows:

```
river (# This should be river: 4 not just river)
atlantic: 1
branch: 1
commonplace: 1
considering: 1
contrary: 1
country: 1
cover: 1
crookedest: 1
crow: 1
degrees: 1
delaware: 1
drainage-basin: 1
draws: 1
fly: 1
forty-five: 1
ground: 1
idaho: 1
journey: 1
longest: 1
longitude: 1
main: 1
miles: 1
missouri: 1
pacific: 1
part: 1
remarkable: 1
safe: 1
seaboard: 1
seems: 1
seventy-five: 1
six: 1
slope: 1
spread: 1
states: 1
supply: 1
territories: 1
twenty-eight: 1
uses: 1
vast: 1
water: 1
ways: 1
world: 1
world--four: 1
```

It looks great and exactly what I am trying to do. Except, see how river at the top of the list doesn't have a count? River appears in the text 4 times so I want a counter for the unique word to count the rivers 4 times while still giving me the output below.

these are the list (temp) and set (unique) I am using for this:

**Unique**

```
{'longest', 'considering', 'receives', 'water', 'discharges', 'atlantic', 'austria', 'part', 'idaho', 'main', 'drainage-basin', 'st', 'twenty-five', 'seventy-five', 'slope--a', 'world--four', 'remarkable', 'rivers', 'country', 'crookedest', 'areas', 'ireland', 'fifty-four', 'portugal', 'valley', 'france', 'almost', 'branch', 'twenty-eight', 'fertile', 'england', 'crow', 'spread', 'italy', 'journey', 'germany', 'river', 'draws', 'exceptionally', 'scotland', 'fly', 'uses', 'supply', 'region', 'rhine', 'ground', 'thirty-eight', 'thames', 'pacific', 'degrees', 'mississippi', 'lawrence', 'six', 'cover', 'subordinate', 'flats', 'navigable', 'area', 'proper', 'states', 'safe', 'wide', 'territories', 'vast', 'hundreds', 'contrary', 'missouri', 'commonplace', 'gulf', 'worth', 'seaboard', 'steamboats', 'wales', 'turkey', 'combined', 'delaware', 'forty-five', 'carries', 'seems', 'reading', 'keels', 'longitude', 'spain', 'ways'}
```

**Temp**

```
['mississippi worth reading about', ' commonplace river contrary ways remarkable', ' considering missouri main branch longest river world--four miles', ' seems safe crookedest river world part journey uses cover ground crow fly six seventy-five', ' discharges water st', ' lawrence twenty-five rhine thirty-eight thames', ' river vast drainage-basin draws water supply twenty-eight states territories delaware atlantic seaboard country idaho pacific slope spread forty-five degrees longitude', ' mississippi receives carries gulf water fifty-four subordinate rivers navigable steamboats hundreds navigable flats keels', ' area drainage-basin combined areas england wales scotland ireland france spain portugal germany austria italy turkey almost wide region fertile mississippi valley proper exceptionally so']
```

If you have any questions please feel free to ask them.

Thanks,

Comment: so you just want to count words in a list of strings?

Comment: So far every element in the unique list is only being printed, How do I put a count so if for example river is the kw more then once that it counts to 2 and eventually gets to 4 as explained above.

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections

temp = ['mississippi worth reading about', ' commonplace river contrary ways remarkable', ' considering missouri main branch longest river world--four miles', ' seems safe crookedest river world part journey uses cover ground crow fly six seventy-five', ' discharges water st', ' lawrence twenty-five rhine thirty-eight thames', ' river vast drainage-basin draws water supply twenty-eight states territories delaware atlantic seaboard country idaho pacific slope spread forty-five degrees longitude', ' mississippi receives carries gulf water fifty-four subordinate rivers navigable steamboats hundreds navigable flats keels', ' area drainage-basin combined areas england wales scotland ireland france spain portugal germany austria italy turkey almost wide region fertile mississippi valley proper exceptionally so']
one_big_string="".join(temp)

print(collections.Counter(one_big_string.split()))
```

> Counter({'river': 4, 'mississippi': 3, 'water': 3, 'drainage-basin':
>   2, 'navigable': 2, 'worth': 1, 'reading': 1, 'about': 1,
>   'commonplace': 1, 'contrary': 1, 'ways': 1, 'remarkable': 1,
>   'considering': 1, 'missouri': 1, 'main': 1, 'branch': 1, 'longest': 1,
>   'world--four': 1, 'miles': 1, 'seems': 1, 'safe': 1, 'crookedest': 1,
>   'world': 1, 'part': 1, 'journey': 1, 'uses': 1, 'cover': 1, 'ground':
>   1, 'crow': 1, 'fly': 1, 'six': 1, 'seventy-five': 1, 'discharges': 1,
>   'st': 1, 'lawrence': 1, 'twenty-five': 1, 'rhine': 1, 'thirty-eight':
>   1, 'thames': 1, 'vast': 1, 'draws': 1, 'supply': 1, 'twenty-eight': 1,
>   'states': 1, 'territories': 1, 'delaware': 1, 'atlantic': 1,
>   'seaboard': 1, 'country': 1, 'idaho': 1, 'pacific': 1, 'slope': 1,
>   'spread': 1, 'forty-five': 1, 'degrees': 1, 'longitude': 1,
>   'receives': 1, 'carries': 1, 'gulf': 1, 'fifty-four': 1,
>   'subordinate': 1, 'rivers': 1, 'steamboats': 1, 'hundreds': 1,
>   'flats': 1, 'keels': 1, 'area': 1, 'combined': 1, 'areas': 1,
>   'england': 1, 'wales': 1, 'scotland': 1, 'ireland': 1, 'france': 1,
>   'spain': 1, 'portugal': 1, 'germany': 1, 'austria': 1, 'italy': 1,
>   'turkey': 1, 'almost': 1, 'wide': 1, 'region': 1, 'fertile': 1,
>   'valley': 1, 'proper': 1, 'exceptionally': 1, 'so': 1})

Comment: Hope I understood your question. You maybe also need to iterate over your "unique" object as use that as a key to the dictionary the Counter gives you

Comment: I like that so far, is there a way to do it without collections being imported?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR your solution, but it seems too complicated, storing lines multiple times, then building dict comprehension, with possible key overwrite, losing the final count of words and keeping the first count of words (which is 1).

There's a shorter and fail-proof approach: you want to leverage the good old `collections.Counter`, but only on some words.

To build this filtered counter, iterate on the words, but filter them out with your unique list (The `set` you've built is ideal to filter out unwanted words very efficiently, let's keep it):

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter(word for line in temp for word in line.split() if word in unique)
```

then print them, sorted:

```
for word,count in sorted(c.items()):
    print("{}: {}".format(word,count))
```

prints (extract):

```
...
reading: 1
receives: 1
region: 1
remarkable: 1
rhine: 1
river: 4
rivers: 1
safe: 1
scotland: 1
seaboard: 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = ['mississippi worth reading about', ' commonplace river contrary ways remarkable', ' considering missouri main branch longest river world--four miles', ' seems safe crookedest river world part journey uses cover ground crow fly six seventy-five', ' discharges water st', ' lawrence twenty-five rhine thirty-eight thames', ' river vast drainage-basin draws water supply twenty-eight states territories delaware atlantic seaboard country idaho pacific slope spread forty-five degrees longitude', ' mississippi receives carries gulf water fifty-four subordinate rivers navigable steamboats hundreds navigable flats keels', ' area drainage-basin combined areas england wales scotland ireland france spain portugal germany austria italy turkey almost wide region fertile mississippi valley proper exceptionally so']
unique = {'longest', 'considering', 'receives', 'water', 'discharges', 'atlantic', 'austria', 'part', 'idaho', 'main', 'drainage-basin', 'st', 'twenty-five', 'seventy-five', 'slope--a', 'world--four', 'remarkable', 'rivers', 'country', 'crookedest', 'areas', 'ireland', 'fifty-four', 'portugal', 'valley', 'france', 'almost', 'branch', 'twenty-eight', 'fertile', 'england', 'crow', 'spread', 'italy', 'journey', 'germany', 'river', 'draws', 'exceptionally', 'scotland', 'fly', 'uses', 'supply', 'region', 'rhine', 'ground', 'thirty-eight', 'thames', 'pacific', 'degrees', 'mississippi', 'lawrence', 'six', 'cover', 'subordinate', 'flats', 'navigable', 'area', 'proper', 'states', 'safe', 'wide', 'territories', 'vast', 'hundreds', 'contrary', 'missouri', 'commonplace', 'gulf', 'worth', 'seaboard', 'steamboats', 'wales', 'turkey', 'combined', 'delaware', 'forty-five', 'carries', 'seems', 'reading', 'keels', 'longitude', 'spain', 'ways'}
words = dict(zip(list(unique), [0 for i in unique]))
for str in temp:
    for w in str.split():
        if w in unique:
            words[w] += 1

for a in sorted(words):
    print('{}: {}'.format(a, words[a]))
```

Comment: I get dict() needs 2 parameters?

Comment: I changed code for initialize words.
What is python's version you used?